# Can't convert UI to PY

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside2

I am using `PySide2` and `PyQt5`. My UI file name is `"unt.ui"`

I wrote:

```
pyside2-uic unt.ui -o unt.py
```

And got error.

```
File 'unt.ui' is not valid
while executing 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\PySide2\uic -g python unt.ui -o unt.py'
```

Then i wrote:

```
pyside2-uic "C:\python\unt.ui" -o "C:\python\unt.py"
```

And got error again.

```
File 'C:\python\unt.ui' is not valid
while executing 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\PySide2\uic -g python C:\python\unt.ui -o C:\python\unt.py'
```

How can I convert it?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "Error: File unt.ui is not valid". My ui file is in my python projects folder

Comment: Are you completely sure that `unt.ui` is a valid UI file created with Designer?

Comment: Yes i created it using Designer and can open it as ui file

Comment: It has only interface now, i want to code it and make it work. (unt.ui is a calculator)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @BehruzYuldashev share the unt.ui file

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I had the same problem, with the .ui file also opening properly in QtDesigner and the correct path supplied for `pyside6-uic`.

In my case I installed `PySide6` in a virtualenv and forgot to switch into it. Running `source .venv/bin/activate` before running `pyside6-uic appmainwindow.ui -o MainWindow.py` fixed the problem.